# Random position from database

Tags: software, database

How do I get a random position in chessbase 13 software from megadatabase to guess the best move , is this facility available in chessbase software which is availabe is softwares like Chess Hero, Or is there any other software provides such facility?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing in Chessbase.

Comment: Not chessbase 13, but the site https://www.chessable.com/ lets you learn openings (and a few endgames) by (among other things) getting random positions.  Same idea, not as large a sample size; it's more focused.

Answer (score 1):

Although it isn't chessbase 13, https://www.chessable.com/ is a site, designed to help you learn chess, that works in a similar manner to that described in the question.

The student gets books (usually openings, but there are some endgames) and learns variations - but the default learning pattern is to be shown random positions from those variations, and "guess the move".  (This isn't really a "guess," since you learned the variation, but still...)

The base part of the site is free (and a number of books are free); there are other learning elements that are only available to paid members.  The "library" is growing, including works by several FMs, IMs, and even a few GMs.

**TL;DR**: It's the same idea as the question, just not on as wide a database.  (One could argue this allows the student to focus on an area; one could also argue it's not as powerful.)

*For full disclosure, I have nothing to do with the site itself, though I am a paying member: I've just had such luck with it I'm like a walking billboard.*

Answer (score 0):

I have looked for similar online. Chessgames.com has a premium guess the move section. I think you can play the Paulsen - Morphy game for free. I am trying to work on putting something together on my site but will keep you posted!